# Record application audio ouput on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, record

I've read some information about recording audio you play on the application (with buttons), but haven't really understood the basics.

What do I need? Can I record audio being played in the application with Remote I/O Unit?

Are there any samples I could study?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want to give you a link to [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802) sample app as a comment.  But SO does not allow me because I do not have 50 reputation.  So here it is.  Good luck.

Comment: Will that sample allow me to record sound produced from the app?